# mongodump only dumps a subset of data

Tags: mongodb

I tried to execute mongodump with the -q parameter.

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 -c reports -q {time:{$lt:ISODate("2016-06-20T00:00:00Z")}} -d testdb -o ./dump/
```

But it dumps only 241512 documents. (according to output of mongodump)
If I execute the same query with a count command it returns 828413 documents.

```
db.getCollection('reports').count({time:{$lt:ISODate("2016-06-20T00:00:00Z")}})
// Output: 828413 
// or
db.getCollection('reports').find({time:{$lt:ISODate("2016-06-20T00:00:00Z")}}).count()
// Output: 828413
```

But if i use itcount() it also returns the wrong number of documents (241512):

```
db.getCollection('reports').find({time:{$lt:ISODate("2016-06-20T00:00:00Z")}}).itcount()
// Output: 241512
```

What's wrong here? Is there an issue in some of the tools? Can anyone help?